# Theorem stating that raising to $\rm n^{th}$ power both sides of an equation *is ok*.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

In a previous question about [“squaring both sides of an equality”](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2024367/why-squaring-the-trigonometric-equation-changes-the-solution/) I made the following observation [in my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2024367/why-squaring-the-trigonometric-equation-changes-the-solution/2025707#2025707).

> 1. Algebra’s fundamental theorem states: *Any* $\rm n^{th}$ order polynomial has $\rm n$ roots.
> 2. Then, if one increase the order of a polynomial by $\rm m$ (let’s say $\rm 1^{st}$ to $\rm 2^{nd}$) the number of roots will increase from $\rm n$ to $\rm n+m$, Therefore raising the power makes things different.
> 3. But raising to the same power both sides of an equation makes the solution set of the $\rm (n+m)^{th}$ order polynomial to contain the solutions set of the $\rm n^{th}$ polynomial.

I don’t have any problem assuming the first 2 paragraphs. However, when I made the last one “But rising to the same power both sides…” unwillingly I made a leap of faith, since it seemed so obvious that it didn’t *deserve* more to say. But now, if any one asks me to quote that, I wouldn’t know any theorem stating that. It is really simple to show it when we have numbers, but not when we have functions (or equations); more importantly, I showed in my 2nd paragraph that it “makes things different…” then, why the resulting solution set *must* contain the solution set of the original problem.

**I can actually prove it, therefore, posting a proof or not is not important**. I just want to know if there is already any *theorem* proving that the **resulting** solutions set of raising both sides of an equation **must** contain the solutions set of the **original** problem, so I can quote it; or it is so trivial that it’s not necessary to quote that at all (though my proof don’t seems to be trivial to me).

**PS1**: Please follow the paragraph as numbered in this question. Not the order of the paragraphs as in the linked answer.

**PS2**: Even though I concentrate in polynomials, it should be noticed that it is *polynomial* at its higher level of abstraction. It could be **any** equation in the form $f(x)=g(x)$, since at this level of abstraction, raising the power in both sides, becomes the *polynominal* $f^n-g^n=0$.

Comment: $\large {f(x) = x^n}\,$ is a *single-valued* function so $\,\large{a= b\,\Rightarrow\,f(a) = f(b)}\ $

Comment: Contrast that to: the root of $\,x = 1\,$ equals the root of $\,2x=2\,$ vs. the root of $\,x^2 = 1\,$ equals the root of $\,2x^2=2.\,$ The former is true because there "root of" is a single valued function, but the latter is not (one could choose either the root $\,x =1\,$ or $\,x = -1).\,$ We partly work around the latter problem by normalizing to a choice of positive roots (or principal branches).

Comment: My comment wasn't actually as accurate as it could be.  It would be more accurate to say that 'f(a)=f(b) --> a=b' if 'f' is bijective.

Comment: @BillDubuque $x^2+x=5$; second order polynomial, 2 solutions.

$(x^2+x)^2=5^2 \Rightarrow x^4+2x^3+x^2=25$; 4th order polynomial; 4 solutions; Is it so trivial?.

Why **exactly** 2 of the last equation, out its 4 solutions **are** the 2 solutions of the former. Forget the examples; I just need a theorem if there is.

Comment: The theorem is in the first comment. It's not clear precisely what is unclear about that to you.

Comment: @lordoftheshadows, not only that commment is not as accurate as it could be: it is false. I'd be a good idea for you to delete it and, if you want, add a new one with closer relation to the truth :-)

Comment: @BillDubuque First comment is the fundamental theorem of algebra. It just tell me that the numbers of roots **must** increase, it doesn’t tell me **why** the solutions set (set of roots) of the original problem *should be in* the solutions set of the “powered” problem, has I claimed on the 3rd comment. The **why** is the theorem I’m looking for.

Comment: @J.Manuel $\ $ By the Factor Theorem $\ f-g\,$ divides $\,f^n-g^n,\,$ so $\, f^n-g^n = (f-g)h\,$ for some polynomial $\,h.\,$ So any root of $\,f(x)=g(x)\,$ is a root of the RHS $\,(f-g)h,\,$ so also a root of the LHS $\,f^n-g^n.\ $ Is that the result you seek?  This is a special case of what I wrote in my first comment, viz. where $\,a,b\,$ are the points of intersection of two function graphs). Also not that powering by $\,n\,$ *multiplies* the degree by $\,n\,$ (but you seem to be *adding* in your question).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a polynomial with $n$ solutions $a_1, a_2, \ldots , a_n$ then you have a factorisation
$$
(x-a_1)(x-a_2)\ldots(x-a_n) = 0
$$

Raising each side to the same power doesn't give you any more roots, just increases the multiplicity of each root. This works when you have $0$ on the right hand side because that is the factorisation that gives you the roots.

I think the question you linked is slightly different because it isn't a polynomial (unless you count the infinite Taylor series). In any case the first answer explained it nicely. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2024377

If you have an equation $f(x) = g(x)$ then 
$$
f(x)^2 = g(x)^2 \implies f(x)^2 - g(x)^2 = 0\implies (f(x) - g(x))(f(x)+g(x))=0$$

so that you have the solution set of $f(x)=g(x)$ (as intended) but also you've obtained solutions for $f(x)=-g(x)$. As you said though, the original solution set is clearly contained in the new equation

edit: if you use other powers then you still have the $f(x)-g(x)$ term in the complete factorisation, same conclusion. I think it's just a natural consequence of your theorem (and would therefore explain it as such), not aware of any other theorem stating that as a result.

Answer (score 1):

When you write $$A=B$$ you are saying that that is on the left hand side of the equal sign is **exactly the same thing** as what is on the right hand side.

How could it be possible the case, then, that if you do something to $A$ and do the same thing to $B$ you do not get the same result?

Equality means that the two things are equal. It is as simple as that.

Comment: The only **exactly the same thing** as I understand would be (not even so sure…) the trivially $\rm 5=5$ (or pick any number). $\rm (4+1)$ is not **exactly the same thing** as $\rm 5$.

Comment: The expression 4+1 denotes **exactly** the same thing as 5. In fact, in many situations the latter is defined to be exactly the former.

Comment: Arithmetic expressions denote numbers. There is exactly one number which is the successor of the successor of the successor of the successor of the successor of zero, and 5, 4+1, 2^2+1, 20-15, and many others are different ways of eriting that very same natural number. When you write 6-1=3+2 you are saying that the left hand side denotes a number, that the right hand side denotes  a number and that the number denotes in each case is exactly the same one.

Comment: I never wrote and I never meant that identities are trivialities: that would be a silly and, to boot, a false claim. Showing that two things are in fact the same things can be very non-trivial.

Comment: You seem to be somewhat confused about what the meaning of equality is. Equality means exactly what I described: two things are equal when they are the same thing, and there is no more to it than that.

Comment: What does it mean so solve an equation such as $2x^2+1=3x^3-2x+4$? It means: to find a number $x$ such that the expressions $2x^2+1$ and $2x^2-2x+4$ denote the same number. In solving such an equation one usually assumes that one has already found the number $x$ in question and tries to find information about it, as much as needed to actually determine it. For example, if we assume that $x$ is a number such that $2x^2+1$ and $2x^2-2x+4$ denote the same number, that is, such that the equation $2x^2+1=2x^2-2x+4$ holds, then it is clear that also the expressions...

Comment: ... $(2x^2+1)^2$ and $(2x^2-2x+4)^2$ denote the same number, that is, that the equation  $(2x^2+1)^2=(2x^2-2x+4)^2$ also holds. Similarly, under that assumption it is also obviously true that $\sin(2x^2+1)=\sin(2x^2-2x+4)$ and that  $e^{2x^2+1}=e^{2x^2-2x+4}$, and many other equations hold.

Comment: Your example: $2x^2+1=3x^3-2x+4$; Your answer: "what is in the left side is **exactly the same thing** as what is on the right side", Conclusion: $2x^2+1$ is **exactly the same thing** as $3x^3-2x+4$. **No** they are different **except** in those (particular) points, that make $2x^2+1=3x^3-2x+4$ an identity. Such points are by definition this equation’s roots. That’s why rising to power (let’s say squaring) both sides of this example makes things different, first of all you change from 3 roots to 6 roots. I must apologize since my previous comments were not that much clear.

Comment: If you actually read what I wrote you will see that I said: we suppose that $x$ is a number such that the expressions blah and blah denote the same value and so on.

Comment: Rising an equality to a power does not change anything. If $f(x)=g(x)$, then $f(x)^2=g(x)^2$. What is not true is that the implication in the converse direction holds. That has **absolutely** nothing to do with what I wrote, and that simply a reflection of the fact that squaring is not an injective function. In any case, you are free to insist in being wrong.